# PHP looping through xml using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

I have been working through this for awhile with no luck.
The xml file is a generated file that I cannot easily edit the structure of to add id's to aid in the looping process.

xml file:

```
<Shipments>
    <Shipment>
        <Packages>
            <Package>
                <TrackingNumber>1234567890123</TrackingNumber>
                <ReferenceNumbers>
                    <Reference1>889</Reference1>
                    <Reference2>9876</Reference2>
                    <Reference3>John Smith</Reference3>
                    <Reference5></Reference5>
                </ReferenceNumbers>
            </Package>
        </Packages>
    </Shipment>
    <Shipment>
        <Packages>
            <Package>
                <TrackingNumber>2345678901234</TrackingNumber>
                <ReferenceNumbers>
                    <Reference1>893</Reference1>
                    <Reference2>9877</Reference2>
                    <Reference3>Joe Blow</Reference3>
                    <Reference5></Reference5>
                </ReferenceNumbers>             
            </Package>
        </Packages>
    </Shipment>
    <Shipment>
        <Packages>
            <Package>
                <TrackingNumber>3456789012345</TrackingNumber>
                <ReferenceNumbers>
                    <Reference1>895</Reference1>
                    <Reference2>9878</Reference2>
                    <Reference3>Jon Doe</Reference3>
                    <Reference5></Reference5>
                </ReferenceNumbers>
            </Package>
        </Packages>
    </Shipment>
    <Shipment>
        <Packages>
            <Package>
                <TrackingNumber>4567890123456</TrackingNumber>
                <ReferenceNumbers>
                    <Reference1>896</Reference1>
                    <Reference2>9879</Reference2>
                    <Reference3>Jack Schmidt</Reference3>
                    <Reference5></Reference5>
                </ReferenceNumbers>
            </Package>
        </Packages>
    </Shipment>
</Shipments>
```

php file:

```
    $input_file=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];  
    $xml=simplexml_load_file($input_file);
    //print_r ($xml);

    foreach ($xml->Shipment as $shipment)
        {
        $tracking = ($xml->Shipment->Packages->Package->TrackingNumber);
        $order = ($xml->Shipment->Packages->Package->ReferenceNumbers->Reference2);
        echo "<br>Tracking#: " . $tracking;
        echo "<br>Order#: " . $order;
        echo "<br>*******************************";
        }
```

All I get is the information from the first instance of  4 times.

EXPECTED/NEEDED RESULT:

```
Tracking#: 1234567890123 
Order#: 9876
******************************* 
Tracking#: 2345678901234 
Order#: 9877
******************************* 
Tracking#: 3456789012345 
Order#: 9878
******************************* 
Tracking#: 4567890123456 
Order#: 9879
*******************************
```

ACTUAL RESULT:

```
Tracking#: 1234567890123
Order#: 9876
*******************************
Tracking#: 1234567890123
Order#: 9876
*******************************
Tracking#: 1234567890123
Order#: 9876
*******************************
Tracking#: 1234567890123
Order#: 9876
*******************************
```

I know the answer is prolly simple I just can't seem to find it...
Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Use `$shipment->Packages->Package->TrackingNumber` instead of `$xml->Shipment->Packages->Package->TrackingNumber` (and that goes for refrence2 as well).

Comment: Yup that did it!!! I can't believe I overlooked that. THANKS!